# Obtener el dato mayor desde distintos campos - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla con 'STOCK_TIENDA1'- 'STOCK_TIENDA2' Y 'STOCK_TIENDA3',
necesito tomar el stock de la tienda que tenga mayor valor y pasarlo a una variable nueva 'TIENDA_MAYOR' quedaria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pense en algo como esto:

```
 SET  VALOR_MAXIMO = (SELECT MAX(T.TIENDA)
 FROM (
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA1 FROM TB1 
 UNION
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA2 FROM TB1
 UNION
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA3 FROM TB1

) T);
```

Pero no me sirve porque el los campos tienen distintos nombres para luego ingresarlo en la función MAX().

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: por favor no escribas todo con mayúsculas

Comment: una duda, tu tabla se llama `TB` y tus campos son `sotck1`,`stock2` y `stock3` ???

Comment: igual, como nota al pie, mas alla que aca tenes una funcion que lo hace, si te sirve el union, solo tenes que renombrar los campos para que se llamen todos iguales (Select STOCK_TIENDA1  as stock.... Select STOCK_TIENDA2 as stock... etc...)

Comment: gbianchi lo probare!

Comment: gbianchi, me funciono! muchas gracias, aunque sea una forma talvez no protocolar, pero si funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tienes necesidad de unir varias veces la misma tabla, en MySQL existe una función para obtener el mayor valor entre varios valores, es la función **[`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)**, la cual según la documentación:

> With two or more arguments, returns the largest (maximum-valued)
>   argument.
>
> ---
>
> Retorna el argumento más grande entre varios argumentos.

Por ejemplo, aquí obtienes el mayor por cada fila:

```
SET  TIENDA_MAYOR = GREATEST(STOCK_TIENDA1, STOCK_TIENDA2, STOCK_TIENDA3) 
FROM TB1  WHERE ...
```

Si quieres el mayor de **toda la tabla** entre esas tres columnas:

```
SET  TIENDA_MAYOR = MAX(GREATEST(STOCK_TIENDA1, STOCK_TIENDA2, STOCK_TIENDA3)) 
FROM TB1 ...
```

### Muy importante: No es *NULL safe*

Ahora bien, hay una advertencia importante en la documentación que es preciso no ignorar:

> `GREATEST()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.
>
> ---
>
> `GREATEST()` retorna `NULL` si algún argumento es `NULL`.

Es un problema muy frecuente en MySQL, pero es muy fácil hacer que nuestra consulta sea *NULL safe* mediante el uso de `COALESCE`:

```
SET  TIENDA_MAYOR = GREATEST(
                              COALESCE(STOCK_TIENDA1,0), 
                              COALESCE(STOCK_TIENDA2,0), 
                              COALESCE(STOCK_TIENDA3,0)
                             ) 
FROM TB1  WHERE ...
```

O bien mediante el uso de `IFNULL`:

```
SET  TIENDA_MAYOR = GREATEST(
                              IFNULL(STOCK_TIENDA1,0), 
                              IFNULL(STOCK_TIENDA2,0), 
                              IFNULL(STOCK_TIENDA3,0)
                             ) 
FROM TB1  WHERE ...
```

Lo que hará `COALESCE` o `IFNULL` es convertir el valor a `0` cuando éste sea `NULL`, evitando así que el resultado sea *nulificado*  al aparecer un sólo valor `NULL`. En definitiva, MySQL no es democrático en muchas funciones :)

Comment: olvide poner el campo 'PRODUCTO', piensa que la primera linea el producto es 'COCACOLA' la segunda linea es 'SPRITE'  servira esta funcion? al menos ahora la corro y no me trae el dato..la revisare

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo da más detalles sobre la pregunta si quieres que mejore la consulta, por lo que se ve se trataría de un `UPDATE` (por el `SET`que usas en ella). Si quieres setear más columnas sólo tienes que ponerlas y si es un  `SELECT` igual, sólo tienes que poner la demás columnas que quieres seleccionar.

Comment: si, tengo datos nulo! debe ser eso. lo pruebo de nuevo y te cuento!

Comment: ahora si, logra el objetivo, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

tambien sirve la respuesta de @gbianchi:

```
 SET  VALOR_MAXIMO = (SELECT MAX(T.stock)
 FROM (
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA1 as stock FROM TB1 
 UNION
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA2 as stock FROM TB1
 UNION
 SELECT STOCK_TIENDA3 as stock FROM TB1

 ) T);
```

Comment: Francisco, en ese caso debiste instar a @gbianchi a escribir su propia respuesta. Y en informática siempre hay que tratar de implementar la solución que sea más óptima. El rendimiento es importante, aún en programas jóvenes en los que se pueda notar poco. Si desde el comienzo optas ante cada problemas por la mejor solución, no tendrás luego que perder tiempo optimizando o tratando de ver en qué parte el programa se ha puesto lento.